# Saving dropdown selected value to variable whilst staying on the same page

Tags: php

I am busy with a project in php where my information for each called page from my menu tab is run in a div with css done around it. I have a drop down I have populated from my sqlite DB. For my project to work right I need to save the selected drop down row number without leaving or refreshing my page if that is possible. I see everybody uses post or get but is there a way to do this without having an action to another page?

Comment: Yes, you can make use of ajax..

Comment: You are looking for javascript / ajax.

Comment: if all you are trying to do is save the selected option index then you can use local / session storage which will keep tally of what was selected without having to resort to  form or Ajax submission. (create on onchange function for the select menu and then set the specified localstorage variable to that selected index value.